# is it possible to package the C so lib into rust binary files

Tags: rust, ffi

When using the rust ffi interop with C, it always contains the .so files in some folder. We alway need to pay attention with the .so file path. is it possible to package the .so files into the rust binary?

Comment: `#[link(name = "library", kind = "static")]`.

Comment: This is not specific to Rust. Even in C, referring to a dynamic library from an executable implies this library stays outside this executable and must be found at run-time. If you don't want that, then you should provide a static library instead of a dynamic one.